# Websocket cleanly disconnects on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, websocket, push-notification, flutter-web, pusher

We have a connection to a pusher websocket. We are sending ping message every 40 seconds.

Library being used: https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel

We are logging into console when a disconnection happens.

It takes account on the `onDone` event here

```
_subscription = _channel!.stream.listen(
    (e) => _handlePusherEvent(e, id),
    onDone: () => _onDone(message: 'onDone'), // Erratic clean disconnection here
    onError: (e) => _onWebsocketError(e),
);


void _onDone({required String message}) {
  print(message);
}
```

The behavior is erratic, sometimes it is done after 7 hours, sometimes it only takes minutes. We are logging ping and pong messages. The ping message log precedes the `onDone` event, so it is not being closed due to no ping message being sent.

Is this some issue on pusher side?

Thank you

Comment: Pings being sent is only half the picture - are you also receiving pongs from the Pusher service?

Comment: I receive the pongs from the pusher service, then there is a ping, no pong, and disconnection. This is one scenario. The other scenario which is less frequent is not getting the pong from them for several minutes, and the disconnection happens after 5 minutes say, with no pong response. So it'd be ping pong ping pong ... ping disconnect. Or ping pong ping pong ... ping ping ping ... ping disconnect

Comment: The behaviour you describe indicates that the server - client network connection has been interrupted in some way. When no pong is received from the server the correct behaviour is to close the connection. You may benefit from catching these cases and initiating a reconnection attempt.

Comment: Well, yeah, that second scenario is the less likely one, we get that 1/100.

Answer (score 1):

To check if there is an issue with Pusher you may need to get in touch with them over at https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/requests/new.

Comment: They said it is from my end, since no error is being sent from them- This is flutter web